# Update ImageMagick Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, apache2, rails, imagemagick

I would like to update my version of ImageMagick.  I originally installed ImageMagick with...

```
sudo apt-get imagemagick
```

Current Version:

```
myapp$ convert -version
Version: ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2014-03-06 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP
```

Location:

```
myapp$ which convert
/usr/bin/convert
```

System:  Ubuntu14.04 / Apache2.47 / Passenger 4.0.5.5 / Rails 4.1.1 / Ruby 2.1.5

I do not have brew installed.  What is the advised way to update?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 is the current version for Trusty. There is nothing to upgrade *as this version was extensively tested with Trusty*.

For available upgrades run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade imagemagick
```

---

*Only if you run in into a bug that you desperately need to fix yourself,* should you compile a newer version:

```
mkdir -p ~/src
cd ~/src
wget http://www.imagemagick.org/download/ImageMagick-6.9.3-1.tar.gz
sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall
sudo apt-get build-dep imagemagick -y
tar xf ImageMagick-6.9.3-1.tar.gz
cd ~/src/ImageMagick-6.9.3-1
./configure
make
sudo checkinstall
```

Comment: After following the installation instructions with no errors I was getting"convert: error while loading shared libraries:" which I fixed with "sudo ldconfig /usr/local/lib". Then I noticed I didn't had support for jpeg files (was getting error "no decode delegate for this image format JPEG"). Now I'm looking for a PPA...

Comment: latest version can be found [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/download/)

Comment: I had to run `ldconfig` after `checkinstall` in order to update the links/bindings.